# What are the chord patterns for Scales other than Major and Minor?

Tags: chords, midi

I know this is a Music Theory exchange but im not, atm trying to jump into the rabbit hole of Music Theory and hopefully an answer is still possible.

I am writing a software program to help people who don't know music theory make chords. Because the chords are intervals, it's relatively easy to describe a chord to a computer. You select a Key like "A Minor" and it will restrict you to the A Minor Scale, and also generate all the chords in A Minor only. I allows for you to change each chord in roman numerals to extended chords like maj7. It works very well for now except..

For Major scales im using

```
        string[] MinorProgressions = new string[] { "MINOR", "DIMINISHED", "MAJOR", "MINOR", "MINOR", "MAJOR", "MAJOR" };
        string[] MajorProgressions = new string[] { "MAJOR", "MINOR", "MINOR", "MAJOR", "MAJOR", "MINOR", "DIMINISHED" };
```

But I don't know what to do with "Melodic Minor" or "Dorian" with respect to the above progressions. Or are most songs in Major or Minor?

Comment: "not, atm trying to jump into the rabbit hole of Music Theory" but then "I am writing a software program to help people who don't know music theory" ?!?

Comment: Yes you can be a programmer and find mathematical patterns in music without diving too deep into all the underlying theory. So yes I built this to help myself but find it useful for others

Comment: chords are NOT intervals (former has 3 notes minimum, latter has 2 notes maximum), however intervals are the key to your answer.  If you know the notes in the MODE, just calculate the intervals between the 1st and 3rd, then the 3rd and 5th, and that will tell you the quality of the chord.

Comment: @TimDavis, you can do anything you like, but you will probably end up with a bad theory program. If you missed the pattern of the modes of the major scale - or just decide to skip even the most basic music theory - you will probably miss a lot more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the 7 diatonic modes are nothing more than the major scale starting on different degrees the chords are also the same, just shifted appropriately.

Example:

Major scale = {Maj, Min, Min, Maj, Maj, Min, Dim}

Minor scale = {Min, Dim, Maj, Min, Min, Maj, Maj}

Dorian starts on 2

Dorian scale = {Min, Min, Maj, Maj, Min, Dim, Maj}

For the rest, {Phrygian, Lydian, Mixolydian, Locrean} start on {3, 4, 5, 7} respectively.  You  might notice that for minor, the chords start in the 6th degree of the major scale (i.e. relative minor).

So, rather than have different arrays for each you can have an index shift and access the exact same data set.

On an other note you may want to add the chords for Harmonic and Melodic minor.  When musicians write in minor keys they frequently use these scales instead of "natural" minor because they have a leading tone to the first note of the minor scale.

Minor starts on the 6th degree of major, i.e. (6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5).  Melodic minor ascending is (6, 7, 1, 2, 3, #4, #5).  So you can figure out the chords the same way as with major, every other note (1, 3, 5).  And it might interest you to know that there are 7 melodic minor modes similar to the 7 diatonic modes based on major.  They are just the melodic minor scale starting on different notes but otherwise same pattern.

Comment: I made this whole thing by noticing patterns, but this pattern I didn't notice. Thanks

Comment: That is okay.   The seven modes are all major, shifted.  But one usually wants a dominant 7th chord on the 5th note to create a resolution to 1.  That goes to a whole other level.   Get what you have done and it will be very cool.  Then you can add to it.